# How can I pass parameter to stored procedure through a query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameter

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(OUT `vote_value` INT, OUT `score` INT, IN `user_id` INT, IN `time_range` INT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    SELECT coalesce(sum(vote_value), 0), coalesce(sum(score), 0)
      INTO vote_value, score
    FROM reputations
    WHERE owner_id = user_id
      AND date_time > CASE time_range
          WHEN 'WEEK' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
          WHEN 'MONTH' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
          WHEN 'YEAR' 
          THEN  unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
          ELSE 1 END;
END
```

As you see my procedure has 4 parameters. Both `vote_value` and `score` have `OUT` direction *(as result)*, And both `user_id` and `time_range` have `IN` Direction. So I have to pass those two which have `IN` direction when I call the procedure.

Ok, I can call procedure about like this:

```
CALL test(@vote_value, @score, 10, 'WEEK');
SELECT @vote_value, @score;
```

It would work as well. But please focus on the third parameter which is `10`. I don't want to pass it manually by hand. I want it be a value from a query. Something like this:

```
CALL test(@vote_value, @score, u.id, 'WEEK');
SELECT id, @vote_value, @score FROM Users u;
```

But it throws *syntax error*. Does anybody know how can I do such a thing? The expected result is [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76d67a1e76d37fc2e2daf737e6eb80fc).

Comment: Didn't I just answer this somewhere else -- with concat+prepare+execute?

Comment: @RickJames You did. and thx

Answer (score 1):

You can pass third parameter value as

`CALL test(@vote_value, @score, (select u.id from Users u), 'WEEK');`

Please put appropriate `WHERE` clause in above inline query.